# BackboneJS and JSON-api wordpress (accessing sub objects for models)

Tags: json, backbone.js

[EDIT] **Answered** [/EDIT]

I've just started with Backbone, and have run into a stumbling block that I can't figure out.

I have the following collection which sends a request to JSON-API on my site to fetch posts by category:

```
Posts.Collections.CategoryPosts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

initialize: function(options) {
    this.id = options.id;

    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

    if(intRegex.test(this.id)) {
        this.url_querystring = '?id=' + this.id;
    }
    else {
        this.url_querystring = '?slug=' + this.id;
    }
},

url: function() {
    return '/api/core/get_category_posts/' + this.url_querystring;
},

model: Posts.Models.CategoryPost
});
```

Now, this works the charm; but the problem is; the JSON for this return is actually:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 10,
    "count_total": 79,
    "pages": 7,
    "category": { ... }
    "posts": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ...
    ]
}
```

So, when my code that uses `fetch()` on the collection tries to assign the return to the individual `Post` models; it only creates one.

How do I tell Backbone that the models should be created using the "post" sub-object in the JSON return? There really doesn't seem to be a whole lot about this out there; or I don't know exactly what to search for?

Any help would be great - preferably a push in the right direction, rather than giving the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in defining a parse function to the collection:

```
Posts.Collections.CategoryPosts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.id = options.id;

        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

        if(intRegex.test(this.id)) {
            this.url_querystring = '?id=' + this.id;
        }
        else {
            this.url_querystring = '?slug=' + this.id;
        }
    },

    // Make sure you parse the correct JSON object!
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.posts;
    },

    url: function() {
        return '/api/core/get_category_posts/' + this.url_querystring;
    },

    model: Posts.Models.CategoryPost
});
```